# Need Guidance in learning advanced Javascript concepts

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am having experience of more than 3+ yrs in ASP.net (Web Forms & MVC) development, I have used Javascript mainly for validations or modifying HTML structure (most of basic stuff) .

I am looking for guidance on:

1. Resource/books to learn **advance Javascript** concepts
2. "Open source projects/ideas" to apply those concepts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Books:

I would first recommend [Professional JavaScript For Web Developers](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/productCd-0764579088.html) by Nicholas C. Zakas. It will give a fairly easier transition to JavaScript than the second book recommendation below.

After that I would recommend [JavaScript Patterns](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596806767.do) by Stoyan Stefanov. This will give you a great foundation to understand how JavaScript framework/libraries like BackboneJS, KnockoutJS and AngularJS do a lot of the things that they do.

---

Training:

If you are so inclined, I highly recommend [Pluralsight's](http://pluralsight.com/training/) course [JavaScript For C# Developers](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/js4cs) by Shawn Wildermuth. It is a great way to see how constructs in C# translate directly or not so directly into JavaScript.

Comment: better than mine. +1 for PluralSight :)

Answer (score 0):

Douglas Crockfords "JavaScript: The Good Parts" is also a great book, I suggest you check out some of his lectures on youtube.

I do suggest you don't pick up a library at first as that will not teach you JavaScript. NodeJS may be of some help if you want to learn the language semantics outside of the web browser.

I really started my JavaScript journey with the free course here: http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/javascript